# Listing several authentication providers within the same authentication manager

Tags: spring-security

I came across this code snippet while debugging an authentication problem :

```
 <security:authentication-manager>
         <security:authentication-provider  user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder hash="sha-256">
                <security:salt-source user-property="dateCreated" />
            </security:password-encoder>
         </security:authentication-provider>
         <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

What I have noticed while debugging and playing around with the user credentials is that if the first authentication-provider (i.e. `userDetailsService`) fails to authenticate my user, a remote call is then made to my LDAP server to try to authenticate my user. However if the first authentication-provider manages to authenticate my user successfully, the second authentication-provider is never called.

My question is does the listing of these authentication providers work in a way that if one fails we should jump to the next? I also wonder if the order of them authentication providers listed within the authentication manager plays a role (from a priority standpoint)? An extra reference from Spring Security's official documentation will be more than appreciated.

Comment: Do not longer use the old xml configuration way for spring. Use the modern annotation based way

Comment: @Jens I am actually maintaining an existant solution. The source code is quite old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Spring Security [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-providermanager):

> Each AuthenticationProvider has an opportunity to indicate that authentication should be successful, fail, or indicate it cannot make a decision and allow a downstream AuthenticationProvider to decide. If none of the configured AuthenticationProviders can authenticate, then authentication will fail (...)

> In practice each AuthenticationProvider knows how to perform a specific type of authentication. For example, one AuthenticationProvider might be able to validate a username/password, while another might be able to authenticate a SAML assertion.

When multiple `AuthenticationProviders` are defined, they will be queried in the order they are declared.
If the first `AuthenticationProvider` cannot come to a conclusion it will allow the next `AuthenticationProvider` to try.